# Prohibited alert sign popup when typing

Tags: 16.04, keyboard

I have Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 running on an HP 250 G5 W4Q07EA laptop. Suddenly, in the last few weeks, a particular problem appeared. When I'm typing, a prohibited sign pops and it stops typing. When the sign goes away, it allows me to continue typing normally. Any suggestions as to what may be causing this issue and ways to fix it?

[image: Image of the problem]

[Video of the problem](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_wQQHLgDE5wU0Eyd2FsWHJjLWs)

Comment: @DavidFoerster The video works fine for me...

Comment: Have you installed one of the various "take a break" applications that forces the user to take short breaks at regular intervals? Check in your Startup Applications.

Comment: @heynnema thanks for the reply, nothing like that installed.. the distro is pretty clean. Just for some document use and internet browsing .

Comment: Nevermind about the video. It appears a recent change in Google Drive isn't compatible with my restrictive web browser privacy settings.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution. The laptop cooling pad was causing the problem. I was searching the problem by trying each one of my external devices,(USBs, HDDs, Mouse, Cooling-Pad, etc.). Now i have only the mouse on my laptop, i removed the pad and it just works the way it's supposed to.
 Thanks everyone.